# How to access environmental variables from docker in python?

Tags: python-2.7, docker

I have a Docker file which list environmental variable as follows:

```
ENV WORKGROUP "my-workgroup"
```

In python file I am accessing it as follows:

```
os.environ['WORKGROUP']
```

When I build the docker it fails with the following error:

```
KeyError: 'WORK_GROUP'
```

The reason is some environmental variables have some default values which I need to set in docker. I can override these inside docker run command when needed. Any idea how can I achieve such a scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am usually doing like this in Dockerfile

`ENV ENV_VAR=some_default_value`

to start that kind of image and override env in image you can do this

`docker run --env ENV_VAR=value_to_override`

ENV_VAR will have `some_default_value` or `value_to_override` when image is started. (not during image build process). and `os.environ['ENV_VAR']` sees that value just fine.

you may try `docker build --no_cache` so you are sure that image is rebuild completely.